# Is there a way to intelligently auto crop photos?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop, adobe-lightroom

I've got 12,000 photos from an event where, on every photo, there's about 10-15% of the photo that needs to be cropped off. It's not the same in every photo, so I can't just do a single batch crop.

What I'm hoping for is with all of Photoshop's new content aware stuff, there's a way for me to say "The person in this photo is the only important thing. Crop around them keeping rule of thirds into consideration."

Can this be done?

Comment: It sounds way too complex for a plugin to do. Even if it's the same person in every photo, it would be too complicated to even detect that. Can you share a sample? Maybe there is a workaround, but in all honesty, I think you will have to do this manually. It will probably even take less time than researching a way to automate it.

Comment: This isn't really that helpful, but I'll say it anyways: You could draw a rectangle in each photo document on its own layer. The rectangle should mark the position / size be the crop area. Then record an Action: **1.** Get selection from the rectangle layer. **2.** Move to the crop tool ( Which will adapt the crop area to that rectangle, depending on your PS version ) then just crop **3.** save. **4.** Then you'd run batch run the Action.

Comment: This way pretty much the only time consuming part would be drawing the rectangle in each image, which would still be freaking time consuming. Plus with this many photos you'd have to take an extra step to save each photo to a format that supports layers, after you've drawn the rectangle and then close the document. -- This is just a thought anyways... Maybe there's some sort of plugin or stand-alone app that automates cropping process a bit better.

Comment: Something like this could be done under certain conditions. See [under this link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageKeypoints.html), the section applications. Still it would not be perfect. Depends though.